# Upgraded Python; Do I have to reinstall all site-packages manually?

Tags: python, pip

I have upraded my Linux distro recently. Python 3.5 was replaced by Python 3.6.

All site packages I have installed with `pip3` are still in the `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory and Python does not find them there now, because it looks in `.../python3.6/site-packages` obviously.

I see the directory contents and I could manually install them again, but that does not look to me like the right way to do it. I could move the contents to the new directory, but again, this seems to me incorrect either.

How am I supposed to handle it properly?

Should I have prepared a `pip3 freeze` list before the upgrade?

*I tried to search, but the keywords are probably too general and got many unrelated answers.*

Comment: You shouldn't install site packages in the first place. Use virtualenvs and install the things you need for each project.

Comment: Do you still have `pip3.5`, or at least a working python3.5? If so you can still do `pip3.5 freeze` or `python3.5 -m pip freeze`. That way, `pip3.6` can rapidly re-install packages from the pip cache.

Comment: @PM2Ring Unfortunately no, the old 3.5 binaries from the old distro version have been removed during the upgrade.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 3.5 was replaced by Python 3.6. But you still have the backup option of using python 3.5.

If you want to use python 3.6 you will have to reinstall all pip packages again for python 3.6. And it makes sense.

Say you were changing from 2.7 to 3.5. You would want to preserve both the environments separately. Hence 3.6 environment is different from 3.5.

A quick way to do this would be to `pip freeze` for 3.5 and then install those dependencies for 3.6.

```
pip freeze > reqs.txt
```

upgrade

```
pip install -r reqs.txt
```

Since you don't have this option anymore, first try and list all packages in your python3.5

for that you can install pip3.5 as answered by @kabanus.

```
sudo apt-get install python3=3.5.1*
sudo python3.5 easy_install.py pip
```

Also it's advised to use virtual environment per project so you can maintain separate environments for each of them.

Comment: As I see running `pip freeze` (saving the output) as a cron job once a day is not a bad idea. Fortunately it is not that much work to reinstall it manually.

Answer (score 8):

I just hit the same problem upgrading from Python 3.6 to Python 3.7, I forgot to run `pip freeze` *before* I upgraded to Python 3.7. The solution that worked is to specify the `--path` option as the *old* `site-packages/` directory (which was not deleted):

```
pip3 freeze --path /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ > python3.6_requirements.txt
pip3 install -r python3.6_requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This would have made things simpler for you to reinstall. Checkout [the description](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/).  Using `freeze` you could have done something like:

```
$ env1/bin/pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
$ env2/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Generally the recommended method is you use a `virtualenv` for site packages, so you don't litter your installation areas, but TBH it never broke something for me. Another option is to check if the linux distribution has the package available for proper retrieval, as in:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-<somemodule>
```

This is what I prefer - and could have been upgraded with the distro. As for what to do now, If you really don't want to re-install everything properly you could try to `cp /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/* /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. The differences between versions are not so great such that I believe most packages would work off the bat. You may have to `sed` to replace `python3.5` with `python3.6` in all files there though. **Forgot** delete all `pyc` files if you do this.

Python modules are self contained enough that if something is broken it can be handled per package, and the site packages are self contained completely, so you could always just remove everything and re-install.

A final note - you can try and install pyton3.5/pip3.5 for your linux, and then do the freeze thing. If there is no package you could  install manually (`whl` or such) or compile a stand alone and configure the site path properly. If you want to keep things on a global site package directory or migrate to `virtualenv` this may be the safest option.

Comment: Thank you. I see I was unprepared. From the options I see now, I will reinstall everything manually. Regarding virtualenvs: I used them to run finished projects.