# PyTorch Installation - PiP - Erorr

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, installation, pytorch

When trying to install PyTorch, by entering the command:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.2+cu113 torchvision==0.11.3+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.2+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

I get the following Error

```
Error - "The Package index page used does not have a proper HTML doctype declaration."
```

it also says to contact the owner of the package index, to get this fixed. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825

Any solutions for this? I want to install PyTorch

**EDIT:** I downloaded the latest version of pip, pip 22.0.3

Comment: What command are you using to install pytorch?

Comment: Hi, i just edited the description above and put the command there.  I'll put it here also, the command is,...  
 pip3 install torch==1.10.2+cu113 torchvision==0.11.3+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.2+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html

Comment: Probably not related, but can you include the python and pip version? `pip3 --version` and `python --version` should do the trick

Comment: do you mean to replace it with "python --version" or have both "pip3 --version" and "python --version" inside of it ?

Comment: would the "--version" come after "install" or before it ? could you show exactly how for both of them where they would be placed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242188/discussion-between-aaossa-and-calculate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's an ongoing issue with `pip==22.0.{0,1,2,3}` (confirm your `pip` version using `pip3 --version` or `pip --version`). They started a migration process to remove an HTML parser [1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825), but it seems like PyTorch didn't notice and now they're trying to solve it ([this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/72045) is the GitHub issue where they're tracking the progress on this matter).

At the moment, it seems like you have these options:

1. Try to use the `pip install` command by adding this flag: `--use-deprecated=html5lib`. For example:

   ```
   pip3 install --use-deprecated=html5lib torch==1.10.2+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
   ```
2. Downgrade pip to a "non-`22.0.*`" version. It seems like the recommended way is to use a version that comes with your Python version [2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825#issuecomment-1025169258):

   ```
   python -m pip uninstall pip && python -m ensurepip
   ```

   Then, use the `pip install ...` command normally.
3. Install PyTorch using a different technique.

Comment: I downgraded the pip version to (21.3.1), but it still does not download pytorch. It says Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.2+cu113 (from versions: none)  Error: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.2+cu113

Comment: I've just used this command and worked for me: `pip3 install torch==1.10.2+cu113 torchvision==0.11.3+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.2+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html`. Did you include the `-f <URL>` part?

Comment: Yes that was included

Comment: For downloading the PyTorch with the PiP 21.3.1 version, i think i might know what the problem is. Right now i have Python 32 Bit. But I actually have a 64 Bit Computer.  Originally when i installed python it went to 32 bit. From seeing some of others that have similar problems, it could be possible that i need to upgrade my Python to 64 Bit to install PyTorch with pip. Do you know how i can upgrade to the Python 64 Bit, without loosing current Python Source Code Files ? i want to do this, but not at the expense of loosing my current python files with code.

Comment: If you remove a Python version, you might lose the libraries that you've installed using pi, but there's no way that you'll lose your *.py code files (files that you have created and you've stored in any folder)

Comment: Just for clarification, so you mean i might lose library packages that i installed with pip ? If so, what would be your recommendation of a method to automatically have those packages re-installed after i download python version 64 bit ?

Comment: You could check out some of the answers in this question: [Upgraded Python; Do I have to reinstall all site-packages manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563909/upgraded-python-do-i-have-to-reinstall-all-site-packages-manually). Freezing your libraries to a file and later installing versions from that file is a good approach.

Comment: Do i do the pip freeze before uninstalling the python 32 bit version ? or am i suppose to to do the pip freeze after first installing the python 64 bit version, than the last step would be to uninstall the python 32 bit version ?

Comment: I would freeze before doing any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
pip3 install torch==2.0.0+cpu torchvision==0.15.1+cpu torchaudio==2.0.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code/commands in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.